# Missing operator in expression when compiling assembly file with masm

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++, x86, masm

MASM is saying "missing operator in expression" but I see no problem with the assembly.

I'm trying to manually call windows syscalls in x86 asm, I've grabbed the syscall offset from fs for NtFlushInstructionCache from https://j00ru.vexillium.org/syscalls/nt/64/

C declaration:
`extern "C" NTSTATUS NewNtFlushInstructionCache(HANDLE ProcessHandle, PVOID BaseAddress, ULONG NumberOfBytesToFlush);`

Here's my asm:

```
.model flat
.486
.code

NewNtFlushInstructionCache PROC
    mov eax, 39h
    xor ecx, ecx
    lea edx, [esp + 4]
    call large DWORD PTR fs:[0C0h]
    add esp, 4
    ret 14h
NewNtFlushInstructionCache ENDP

END
```

The error is "missing operator in expression" on this line: `call large DWORD PTR fs:[0C0h]`
Any help? Can fs not be accessed directly from assembly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `LARGE` modifier for the memory operand is an artifact of the [IDA/IDA Pro](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/) disassembler and not understood by MASM. In MASM it is simply done without specifying `LARGE`:

```
call DWORD PTR fs:[0C0h]
```

`LARGE` is a memory model, and not a modifier for memory operands.

By default *FS* and *GS* are set to `ASSUME FS:error` so when those segment registers are used they will produce an *Error A2183*. `ASSUME FS:nothing` overrides the behaviour and allows you to use *FS* freely. Place `ASSUME FS:nothing` at some point before using *FS* like this:

```
ASSUME FS:nothing
call DWORD PTR fs:[0C0h]
```